# Windows API C++ | Problem with GetOpenFileName / OPENFILENAME

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I'm new to C++
I need to return the path to the file that the user has selected. For this i use winapi -> OPENFILENAME. When i try to return file path, i get only  1 character ("C" for disk C).
My code:

```
LPWSTR fileBuffer = new wchar_t[256];
OPENFILENAME ofn = { 0 };
        ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
        ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
        ofn.lpstrFile = fileBuffer;
        ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
        ofn.nMaxFile = 256;
        ofn.lpstrFilter = NULL;
        ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
        ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
        ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
        ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
        ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn) == TRUE)
{
    printf("File name: %s\n", ofn.lpstrFile);
}
```

i tried to increase the buffer size, return the value of ofn.lpstrFile. The first does not change anything, the second returns a int value of disk letter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `wchar_t` (needed by `OPENFILENAME`) which is not the same as `char` (as expected with `printf()`) if you are using wide APIs on Windows.

Use `wprintf()`, or you can use `%S` (capital) to tell `printf()` to print wide characters.

Comment: Or `%ls` - which works on both `printf` and `wprintf`.  `%S` always means the opposite encoding of the api - which can be confusing sometimes.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to loop through lpstrFile, but the size of this property is 8, in the end I only went through 4 elements

Comment: Alternatively, since the code is using the `TCHAR`-based `GetOpenFileName()` (instead of using the `wchar_t`-specific `GetOpenFileNameW()` directly), you can use `_tprintf("%s")` to match the `TCHAR` nature of the API. But, better to just call `GetOpenFileNameW()` directly instead, and then use `wprintf()`. You should write code that either uses `TCHAR` APIs everywhere, or uses `WCHAR` APIs everywhere. Don't mix APIs of different types.